# One badge awarded twice, also on meta site

Tags: support, badges

I have earned the yearling badge twice, just a few days apart, in this year, on programmers: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/16658/fejesjoco?tab=badges

I also got them here on this meta site, where I have never contributed anything before this: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16658/fejesjoco?tab=badges

Looks like a bug to me, I haven't seen this behavior on other SE sites yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.

The rules for the Yearling badge are quite simple, it divides your reputation by the number of years you have been a member and if the answer is > 200 you get a Yearling badge per year.

So if in your first year you earn less than 200, but in the second you earn more (as you have done), you'll get two badges in quick succession.

As there is no separate meta rep you get the Yearling here if you get the Yearling on the main site.